# How to create an Jsoup Selector with an AND operation?

Tags: java, html-parsing, css-selectors, jsoup

I want to find the following tag in a html.

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/AAA" class="link">AAA</a>
```

I know I can use a selector like **a[href^=http://www.google.com/]** or **a[class=link]**.
But how can I combine this two conditions?

Or is there a better way to do this? Like regex? and how?
Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just combine them in a single CSS selector.

```
Elements links = document.select("a[href^=http://www.google.com/][class=link]");
// ...
```

or

```
Elements links = document.select("a.link[href^=http://www.google.com/]");
// ...
```

Considering regex makes no sense with such a world class HTML parser.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But I'm thinking if I can check the "AAA" part in the selector directly. Both "AAA" must be the same to meet my condition.