# using logical or,not,and in jsoup selectors

Tags: java, html, jsoup

Using this

```
for (Element link : links) {
    String linkHref = link.attr("href and !#");       
    String linkText = link.text();       
}
```

i can get all the links which has `"a href=.."`

However, there are some

```
href="#"
```

that i don't need in my string.
So i need to do something like

```
String linkHref = link.attr("href and !#")
```

i.e i don't want to save the link that has `"#"` as href.

is that possible or do i have to use regular expression instead ?

Please help.

Comment: This looks like neither jQuery nor CSS. Please tag and title your question properly, and read http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: You are asking about a specific API -- a specific library. That's probably fine, but you need to indicate *what* library you're asking about. For example, your `Element` obviously isn't [the `org.w3c.dom.Element` interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Element.html), since that interface doesn't have an `attr` method.

Comment: May be all you need is a simple check like this: `String linkHref = link.attr("href"); if (linkHref == "#") continue;`

Comment: Oh i am really sorry. I was using jsoup library.

Comment: @BoyLittUp Didn't my answer solve your problem. Just asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading your question, it looks like you want to **Select all anchor tags which do not have '#' as href**. You can use [:not Selector](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax):

```
Elements links = doc.select("a[href]"); // All anchor tags with href
links = links.select(":not(href='#')"); // Filter out links which do have href=#
```

Answer (score 2):

**Jsoup** select accept comma for **Selector combinations**

```
doc.select("[href], [src]");  // href **OR** src
```

For **AND** Just combine them in a single CSS selector. Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7577653/1283715).

```
doc.select("a[href][:not(href='#')]");
```